# Scanning information from file in c++

Tags: c++, text-files, scanf

I have a file with the following information:

```
INTERSECTIONS:
1   0.3 mountain and 1st
2   0.9 mountain and 2nd
3   0.1 mountain and 3rd
```

How do I scan in c++ so that it scans the first number and stores it in an int, then scans the next number and stores it separately, then stores the name of the streets in an a string? I just switched from c so I know how to do it in C just by using

```
fscanf("%d %lf %s", int, float, string);
```

or

> fgets

with strings but don't know how to do this in C++. Any help would be appreciated

main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include <fstream>
#include<cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "vertex.h"
#include "edge.h"
#include "global.h"
using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ){
    if(argc != 4){
        cout<< "usage: "<< argv[0]<<"<filename>\n";
    }
    else{
        ifstream map_file (argv[3]);
        if(!map_file.is_open()){
            cout<<"could not open file\n";
        }
        else{
            std::string line;
            std::ifstream input(argv[3]);
            int xsect;
            int safety;
            std:string xname;

            std::list<vertex> xsection;
            std::list<edge> EdgeList;

            while (std::getline(input, line))
            {
              std::istringstream iss(line);

                iss >> xsect >> safety;

               std::getline(iss, xname);
            }

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Tip: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/

Comment: i just edited to show my main and I tried one of the below answers. Giving me an error on the "iss(line)"

Comment: Please have another bash at formatting (too many blank lines for a start).

Comment: blank lines are for the rest of my program. Formatting is different to each person and I'm just following my professors formatting. 
I don't get why its so much harder to scan a file in c++ than in c. The internet seems to not have the answer to something that is easy to do in C

Comment: The blank lines in this forum make it more difficult to read as scrolling is required. As to C++ - just takes getting use to. It is better because it is type safe. Do not have problems with the format string being incorrect compared to the pointers in the rest of the arguments.

Comment: ok well still getting an error. And i've looked around and there seems to be hundreds of way to do it except none of them take into account that there maybe multiple data on one line that needs to be scanned into different data types.

Comment: is there anyway I can just scan in one at a time instead of scanning in the entire line? As in scan in the first number and store it and then scan the next and store it like you do in C?

Comment: (please at least get a nickname instead of a number!) - read about C++ streams. Plenty of good examples and tutorials on the web.

Comment: to tell you the truth ive been looking for the past few hours on how to do this....all the examples are on scanning single data types in one line. Either a string, an int, etc. No examples are given on scanning multiple data types on one line, hence i come here for help.

Answer (score 4):

It's enough with [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and the standard C++ stream input operator:

```
std::string line;
std::ifstream input(...);

while (std::getline(input, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    int v1;
    double v2;
    std::string v3;

    iss >> v1 >> v2;

    std::getline(iss, v3);
}
```

Comment: in the std::ifstream input(...) do I put in the file name where the "..." is?

Comment: @dwong Yes, instead of the dots put your filename there. What errors do you get? Have you included the correct header?

Comment: @dwong By the way, don't forget to put in an extra `std::getline` for the first `"INTERSECTIONS:"` line.